# An object factory dictionary in C++

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, stdmap

I need to implement a static map that enables me to retrieve new objects given a string:

**Header:**

```
static const map<string, function<void(MyObject)>> Dictionary;
```

**Source:**

```
const map<string, function<void(MyObject)>> * const ObjectDictionary = boost::assign::map_list_of
("Car", new MyCarObject())
("Ship", new MyShipObject());
```

However I'm having issues when compiling:

```
'<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::pair<const char *,MyCarObject *>'
```

Nor I'm sure about the usage of this Factory.

How could I implement this behavior in C++?

---

Note: what I'm trying to do is to port some code I did in past from C# to C++:

```
public static class MyFactory
    {

        public static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<MyObject>> ObjectDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Func<MyObject>>()
        {
             ["Car"] = () => new MyCarObject(),
             ["Ship"] = () => new MyShipObject(),
        };

    }
```

So I could read a text file and create objects given a string:

```
var getObject = default(Func<MyObject>);

CurrentObjectDictionary.TryGetvalue(objectName, out getObject);

if(getObject != null)
{
    MyObject = getObject();
    //MyObject.Data = ...
    //store
}
```

Comment: const map<string, function<void(MyObject)>> the second parameter is a function not an object, whereas ("Car", new MyCarObject()) contains a string and a MyCarObject.

Comment: I see..., it is a clear mistake there. Unfortunately I have not enough knowledge yet for expressing a function that creates an object. Could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: What you need to do is create a typedef std::function<MyObject(void)> function_t. Create your factory functions, function_t func = myfactoryfunc. Add the <string, myfactoryfunction> to your map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize the map directly with creator functions, without the boost roundtrip.

```
    const std::map<std::string, std::function<unique_ptr<Object>()>> dict{
    {"car", [](){ return std::make_unique<MyCarObject>();}},
    {"ship", [](){ return std::make_unique<MyShipObject>();}}
    };
```

http://cpp.sh/5uzjq

Usage:

```
auto vehicle = dict.at(vehicle_type)();
```

Note: if you're only dealing with nullary constructors, you can even  insert just the `&std::make_unique<T>` into the map:

```
const map<...> dict{
    {"car", &std::make_unique<Car>},
    {"ship", &std::make_unique<Ship>}
};
```

Comment: only if its c++11 onwards maybe.

Comment: If he's using std::function its c++11. Would surprise me to find someone using c++03 still, unless they had a real reason to.

Comment: Could you please explain what is the meaning and the point of the curly braces next to `Object` with those "yup" and "nope" strings. Seems the constructor, after seeing the linked code.

Comment: @SamerTufail: question is tagged c++ so it means c++11 in the year 2017. If not, it should tagged c++03.

Comment: @Klaus if that was the case there wouldn't be a reference to boost assign or I wouldn't expect that to be there.

Comment: @Sturm since C++14 you can construct 'most' objects using curly braces instead of round braces.  "Uniform initialization" is the term used for this: objects are initialized much like structs now.  The main point has become hidden by this, though, so I'll adapt it to reflect your C# code.

Comment: @Sturm By the way, if you're coming from .NET where objects are collected automatically, it's wise to learn to use `unique_ptr` and `make_unique` from the start, so that you avoid memory (and other) leaks.

Comment: @SamerTufail: Using boost did not mean that you do not use recent c++ compiler. If you use something from bust which is not longer needed it simply can indicate that the programmer did not know all features of current standard or how this new features can be used to replace external "foreign" libraries.

Comment: @Klaus C++11? What about C++14 and the soon-to-be C++17?

Comment: @Quentin: If you want to start a request about tagging start a discussion on meta please. I believe the tag c++ is not intended to define a version of c++. So a reader have to look for the modification date of the entry for meant version? For clarification a question should have a tag for c++<version> if it matters.

Comment: @Klaus I'm actually agreeing with you about the use of [c++], but why would the implied version today be 11 and not 14?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Transport
{
public:
    virtual ~Transport();
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Car : public Transport
{
public:
    virtual ~Car();
    virtual void foo(){ };
};

class Boat : public Transport
{
public:
    virtual ~Boat();
    virtual void foo(){ };
};

typedef boost::function<Transport*()> factoryfunc;

template<typename T>
static std::unique_ptr<T> CreateObject()
{
     return std::unique_ptr<T>{new T()};
}

class foo
{
public:
    foo()
    {
       map_.insert(std::make_pair("car", CreateObject<Car>));
       map_.insert(std::make_pair("boat", CreateObject<Boat>));
    }
    std::map<std::string, factoryfunc> map_;
};
```

You can use this like:

```
foo obj;
Transport* carobj = obj.map_["car"]();
```

This is just an example and to give you an idea. There is dynamic allocation there without a delete etc which you might want to refine. Key thing to notice is what is being added to the map on insert. Its not the actual object but a function of the signature mentioned. I then call the function to get the object in return like: `Transport* carobj = obj.map_["car"]();`

Comment: I agree with the idea.

You can move the `template<typename T>` from class scope to method scope: `T* Factory::Create<Car>`.  Next, you can eliminate the `Factory` alltogether to create a free function `T* Create<T>`.

Next, you will probably want to express ownership and return a `unique_ptr<T>` instead of a raw pointer.

... and then you end up with `std::make_unique<T>`.

Comment: Agreed on moving scope and smart ptrs. I would use smart pointers yes, since im not sure on wether he requires a shared or unique I left it open.

Comment: The `Create` function has unique ownership.  It transfers that ownership to the caller.  The caller can do what he thinks fit: move ownership on or share it.  Converting a `unique` into a `shared` is free.  (Shared ownership is a very rare thing - a very interesting article on this https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/)